# Signal power depending on FFT bin size

Tags: fft, dft, white-noise

I have read the following quote from a different post:

> If the noise is white (spread evenly across frequency), then the
> power will be distributed equally to each bin, and as we increase the
> number of bins, the amount in each bin will reduce accordingly (this
> is the "FFT noise floor").

FFT is the discrete sampling of the DTFT at frequencies $\omega = 2π\frac{k}{N}$, so how can the PSD change (therefore the DFT) if the DTFT is invariant to the DFT length?

Comment: The PSD is defined as the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation sequence. The autocorrelation of white noise is a delta, which means the spectrum is flat. Additionally, if the noise is white, the statistical second moments of the signal are zero everywhere except for when there is no time-lag. This means the correlation matrix is an identity matrix scaled by the variance of the noise. This implies the flat spectrum is scaled by the variance.

Comment: There is not necessarily a direct relationship between the power spectrum (power in the signal) and the PSD (Fourier transform of the signal’s autocorrelation sequence).

Answer (score 3):

The PSD doesn't change – the D stands for Density, i.e. "how much power is there per bandwidth), and with an increased DFT length, there's less bandwidth per bin.

Comment: So this means the power itself changes? and the PSD doesnt change because some sort normalization? do we normalize by the total sum of the power?

Comment: No, as said in my answer. No, as said in my answer. No, as said in my answer!

Comment: The PSD simply *does not change* because you're doing something different with the signal (just as the size of the world doesn't change just because you're looking through a looking glass). The DFT's output changes – but that's simply not the same as the PSD!

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as total energy not changing, but since DFT length dictates frequency resolution, the power of each band will be less dense.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).